# Android - Pick file from every external sources

Tags: android, android-intent, dropbox

my intention is to read each type of file from external sources using this code:

```
        IntentchooseFile = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        chooseFile.setType("file/*");
        Intent intent = Intent.createChooser(chooseFile, "Select File");
        startActivityForResult(intent, ACTIVITY_CHOOSE_FILE);
```

Android let me choose where to get the file. In particular in my phone I can select the default File manager, Dropbox or Google Drive. When I get into the file manager I have no problem, when I get into Dropbox I can choose files only if I select "show all" (and everything after works fine), and in Google Drive I can se all my files but I can't select anything.

What am I doing wrong ? Am I missing some permissions or do I have to modify the `chooseFile.setType("file/*")` line? Thank you everybody!

Comment: `file/*` is not a valid MIME type pattern. Try `*/*`.

Comment: Thank you bery very much!! Is there the possibility to set an extension so that the chooser will let me see only the files with that extension?

Comment: Not that I am aware of.